# mapStateToProps gets new props but unable to invoke componentWillReceiveProps

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am using React: 16+ and react-redux: 6+

I wired all the Actions and Reducers. And, on the click of a button, I am able to call mapStateToProps() but after that componentWillReceiveProps or shouldComponentUpdate are not getting called.

Here is my code:

```js
class HeaderContainer extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super();

        this.props = props;
        this.state = {
            headerBtn: []
        }
    }

    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
        console.log(nextProps);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <HeaderComponent className="flx-n-grow"
                             headerBtns={this.props.headerBtns}
                             selectExchange={this.props.selectExchange}/>
        )
    }
}

const mapStateToHeaderProps = (state) => {
    console.log("received new props");
    console.log(state);
    console.log(state.HeaderReducer.headerBtns);
    return {
        headerBtns : state.HeaderReducer.headerBtns
    }
}

const mapDispatchToHeaderProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        selectExchange: (exchanges, exchange) => {
            dispatch(HeaderAction.selectExchange(exchanges, exchange));
        }
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToHeaderProps, mapDispatchToHeaderProps)(HeaderContainer);
```

All the console.log inside of mapStateToProps are getting called but componentWillReceiveProps or shouldComponentUpdate are never getting called.

Comment: I have used the same code and componentWillReceiveProps is getting called as and when the props from store is updated. Can you try with     "react": "16.8.6",
 "react-redux": "7.0.1","redux": "4.0.1"?

Answer (score 0):

```
constructor(props) {
    super();

    this.props = props;
    this.state = {
        headerBtn: []
    }
}
```

try adding the props to the super

```
super(props);
```

Comment: `this.props = props;` is redundant, the constructor is handling this.

Comment: https://overreacted.io/why-do-we-write-super-props/ if you don't access `this.props` right in constructor it does not matter if you pass `props` into `super()` call or don't.

Answer (score 0):

After 24 hours of POCs and debugging it turns out that my reducer was not returning a new object despite using spread operator:

```
let newState = {...state};
newState.name = ...
```

So, what I read from the Internet, and Redux troubleshoot doc in specific, is that if the state changes mutably then mapStateToProps will not be called. This seems incorrect. In my case or in any case of mutation of state, Redux does call mapStateToProps. It simply wouldn't call shouldComponentUpdate().

The reason being spread operator only shallow-copies the object. So, if there are nested objects in an object, spread operator would retain the reference of the object and hence, once the inner object is updated the original state is mutated. To avoid such scenarios, always use any tool that deep-copies an object.

```
_.cloneDeep(stateCopy, stateInitial)
```

worked in my case.

By the way,

```
console.log(newState === state)
```

returned false, meaning the state was not mutated, it was indeed a cloned state. Very strange. :(

### Update

Refrain from using the spread operator. It does not do a deep copy. It is only good for cases where the state has a simple key-value pair. For complex object nested within objects, spread operator will fail badly.